# Showing properties of share settings with Powershell

Tags: powershell, share, windows-server-2019

I need to check if this checkbox is enabled or disabled: [image: Picture of the needed checkbox]

Is there anyway i can check this with powershell, because there something like 1400 shares I need to check?

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Using [Get-SmbShare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/get-smbshare) and inspect the `CachingMode` property perhaps?

Comment: Hey Theo, yeah i've tried ```Get-SmbShare | Format-List -Property Name,CachingMode | Where-Object -Property CachingMode -eq Manual``` but this is not giving me an output the problem is the Where-Object without the Where-Object it works. I just want to display the ones with the CachingMode on Manual.

Comment: Bad syntax, try `Get-SmbShare | Where-Object {$_.CachingMode -eq 'Manual'} | Format-List -Property Name,CachingMode`. All `Format-*` cmdlets are for **display purposes only** and ruin the data itself. That is why you cannot pipe it through to a Where-Object clause

Comment: Sure, it just depends on what property you wish to report

Comment: Thanks a lot Theo. Can you post your comment as an answer. Would be perfect

Answer (score 0):

The cmdlet [Get-SmbShare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/get-smbshare) returns objects with losts of useful properties. One of which is called `CachingMode`.

To report on shares where the CachingMode is set to 'Manual' for instance, you can do

```
# as example only output on screen
Get-SmbShare | Where-Object {$_.CachingMode -eq 'Manual'} | Format-Table -Property Name, CachingMode
```

If you want to save this data to csv , remove the `Format-Table` cmd and do

```
Get-SmbShare | Where-Object {$_.CachingMode -eq 'Manual'} | 
               Select-Object Name,CachingMode | 
               Export-Csv -Path 'X"\Somewhere\ShareCaching.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```